# Imagemagick Linking to QT and mingw32-make: *** [debug] Error 2

Tags: qt, compiler-construction, qt4, imagemagick

I created an application using Imagemagick library with Qt on Mac.

Now that I want to deploy the application for windows:

- I installed the imagemagick library
  on my pc,
- I installed the SDK version of QT 4.7
- I added my include and lib paths

And when I go run the application I'm getting errors that I think they are related to mingw32.
here are the build issues:
[image]

and here is the compile output:
[image]

Can someone Identify the error ?
What do I have to do to deploy the application for windows?

I also tried to use a Mingw32 version of my library but again, It didnt work:
[image]

When I put -lmagick after the lib it says file lmagick cannot ne found
and when I try to build unticking the shadow build checkbox in the build settings, it give me the errors in the first screenshoot. Thank you

Comment: Did you included library? I can see only path to it in your .pro file

Comment: Hi Pie_Jesu!
I have installed library and included the paths on my .pro file.
what more is there to do?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4141312/how-to-link-imagemagick-library-to-qt).

Comment: Hello Hmuelner I have downloaded the mingw32 version of the library from (ImageMagick-i686-pc-mingw32.tar.gz), I exctracted the file into my dirs and I tried to run it with Qtcreater but It didnt work(check the last screentshoot). Thanks for responding to that

Comment: Try forward slashes ("/") instead of backslashes in your first version of RightDoneIt.pro. In your second version you don't need the quote function (you only need it if you have spaces in you path). qmake tells you it cannot open (i.e. create) you Makefile. Somewhere you have a superfluous slash at the end of a path (did you see the double slash before Makefile.debug?).